# Tensorflow Session.Run gives empty Output tensor when run on Android device but works fine when run on Ubuntu

Tags: android, c++, api, tensorflow

I have a pre trained Tensorflow protobuf that I load from C++ API and build using Bazel. I get expected output tensors when I run the generated executable on Ubuntu. But when I compile the exact same code for Android using Bazel, I get empty output tensors.

Code I use to get the output (same code used in both Ubuntu and Android):

```
auto statusPred = session->Run(run_options, input, vNames, {}, &answer, &run_metadata);printLog(answer.size());
```

The answer has size 0 on Android, but has the right expected size when I run the executable, also built using Bazel on UBuntu machine.

Am I missing something fundamental here? Is there a difference between the way computation is done on Ubuntu and Android because of which the output tensor is empty?

Comment: What is the return value from `session->Run()` when running on Android?

Comment: @mrry Ah, There seems to be an issue, the output of the status is as follows:


09-12 11:08:16.442 14372 14372 D FromCPP: : Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Floor' with these attrs.  Registered kernels:
09-12 11:08:16.442 14372 14372 D FromCPP: :   <no registered kernels>
09-12 11:08:16.442 14372 14372 D FromCPP: : 
09-12 11:08:16.442 14372 14372 D FromCPP: :   [[Node: dropout/dropout/Floor = Floor[T=DT_FLOAT](dropout/dropout/add)]]

Comment: @mrry I got thrown off because the same code worked when I compiled for Ubuntu.

Comment: It looks like "Floor" is used under the hood by some Op? Does anybody know a fix for this?

Comment: Fixed it by adding "cwise_op_floor.cc", to file tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD, under filegroup android_extended_ops_group1. I see that the latest version has this Op included under the same filegroup though: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD#L987

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding "cwise_op_floor.cc", to file tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD, under filegroup android_extended_ops_group1. I see that the latest version has this Op included under the same filegroup though: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD#L987